# Upgrading Jest to v29 - Error Test environment jest-environment-jsdom cannot be found

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

Has anyone successfully upgraded to latest Jest version `29`?
I'm receiving an error:

```bash
Error: Test environment jest-environment-jsdom cannot be found. Make sure the testEnvironment configuration option points to an existing node module.
```

Answer (score 255, accepted):

Jest team added more [descriptive error message](https://github.com/facebook/jest/releases/tag/v28.0.1) in version `28.0.1`

```bash
Error:...
As of Jest 28 "jsdom" is no longer shipped by default, make sure to install it separately.
```

Installing `jsdom` package resolves the issue:

```bash
# npm
npm install -D jest-environment-jsdom
# yarn
yarn add -D jest-environment-jsdom
```

Comment: Indeed. Cf. https://jestjs.io/docs/upgrading-to-jest28

Comment: The fact that it is no longer shipped by default, does that mean that we shouldn't use it?

Comment: you can also try adding it as a dev dependency: npm install -D jest-environment-jsdom

Comment: @J.DavidEscobar agree, edited to install as dev dependency

Comment: @marko424 i don't think it's so obvious. most people come here for guidance and reason why it's separated. I'm sure everyone is capable of installing another dependency just reading the error message

Comment: After installing, you need to update scripts in package.json `"test": "jest --verbose"` to make it work properly

Comment: @Jordan no it doesn't mean that.